# In android get the incoming phone number display in Toast?

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I run my code in emulator display contact number in toast.
When I run in my phone not display contact number in toast.

please help me for this solution.

**this is my AndroidManifest.xml file code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my_call_detact">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

**this is my MainActivity.java file code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        PhoneStateListener callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber)
            {
                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone Is Riging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone is Currently in A call"+ incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }

                if(state==TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"phone is neither ringing nor in a call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
        telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE)
    }
}
```

give me the solution or advice why this code is not working in phone?

Comment: in every toast line , write a log.e() under the toast and check if toast line in ran or no . Maybe your desired line is not executed in a real device (timing issue) . You could use snackbar (rapidly displaying)

Comment: all toast messages work properly. The main problem is when I received a call  "Phone is Currently in A call" this message display but I want to this type of message "Phone is Currently in A call 1234567890". which number from the call is coming. phone in not display the number.

Comment: Hi Could you take a image displaying the toast message (that is not displaying the phone number).If I understand correctly you say : I have the toast message but without the phone number. Is that right? Before sending the image please do this test: create a local parameter as string and assign the phone number to it(with all trimming) and also use logcat for displaying of 'incommingNumber' and the new parameter for comparing.